# The grammar of some sentences

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, ellipsis

Are there sentences correct grammatically please? (I don't think so!)

*They think that the way things are need to be changed.*
*Why do you think it strange?*

I think they should be:
*They think that the way things ar**e,** need to be changed.*  (a comma)
*Why do you think it **is** strange?* (a verb)

Comment: For the first one, I'd simply add an "s" (needs) because it's the way that needs to be changed, not the things. No commas are needed because "the way things are" is the subject, and "are" is the verb, and you do not use a comma between the subject and the verb. The second sentence is correct, and so is your suggestion. Consider "Do you think **me** strange!?" = "Do you think **i'm** strange!?" You might have been confused by the fact that "it" is the third person for both "I" and "me".

Comment: You don't need the comma. The subject of the subordinate clause is "the way things are __" and this must not be separated from the verb "need" by a comma. Gap represents "x way", which is the missing complement of "are".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is incorrect, but the error does not lie in the pointing. *The way things are* is the subject of its clause; it is on any analysis singular<sup>†</sup>, so it requires its verb to be inflected for third person singular:

> . . . the way things are need***s*** to be changed.

The second sentence is fine. Several verbs which express opinion or evaluation license two complements, an object (OBJ) and a secondary complement modifying the object (OC):

> `SUBJ VERB     OBJ OC`
>   `I    think    him strange.`
>   `I    consider him strange.`
>   `I    deem     him strange.`
>   `I    judge    him strange.`
>   `I    adjudge  him strange.`
>   `I    believe  him strange.`
>   `I    count    him strange.`

This construction is in free variation with infinitival and content clauses; all three have exactly the same meaning:

> Infinitival clause –
>   `SUBJ VERB   OBJ to be OC`
>   `I    think  him to be strange.`
>
> Content clause –
>   `SUBJ VERB  (that) OBJ {are/am/is} OC`
>   `I    think (that) he       is     strange`.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>That is, you may parse it as a noun phrase headed by *way* or as a sort of periphrastic relative clause, with *the way* = *how*</sub>.

Comment: it is worth mentioning that "it" works as both forms of the pronoun for the third person. Therefore, the OP might have thought the second sentence was written like "I think he strange" instead of him, which would justify the addition of "is".

Comment: Can a subject ended by a verb to be(like *are* in this case). If that so, can I say "The way things are **are** causing more problem"?

Comment: @user178049 It is indeed possible, even though "way" is still the subject of the noun phrase and it is singular, so it would be "The way things are **is** causing problems.

Comment: @user178049 No. What underlies the construction is two different propositions: *Things are this way* and *This way **is** causing more problems.*

Comment: There may be dialects in which the verb "to think" doesn't license any object complement and some others (like "to judge") license infinitives but not simple adjectives.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan I agree that the infinitival, and to a lesser extent the secondary complement, are pretty rare in colloquial English. I'm sympathetic to describing this as a 'dialect' phenomenon--I too consider academic/literary/bureaucratic Englishes dialects--but I worry that this would confuse many of our users, who think of 'dialect' as a designation for regional or ethnic variations.