# What does "You know it to be true" mean? Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I came across this example.
In the book, the girl deceives and convinces the main character of her goals and at the end says :

> You know it **to be** true.

I have a question, why is there no is here?

> You know it **is** true.

I know what else you can say:

> You know it **is to be** true.

But why is it just **to be** in my example? I will be glad to help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The grammar of some sentences.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110965/the-grammar-of-some-sentences) Which specifically addresses the alternative phrasings *I think **him to be** strange* and *I think **[that] he is** strange*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's formal English.

> You know it to be true.

means

> You know that it is true.

Other examples:

> I have always **known Sarah to be** (=known that Sarah is) an honest woman, so I believe what she says.

> The authorities **know him to be** (=know that he is) a cocaine dealer.

It's often used passively:

> The pilots **were** experienced and **known to be** very competent.

> Although it is the most commonly used operating system in the country, within tech circles **it is known to be** sloppy and inefficient.

<sup>It turns out to be a Star Wars quote, I am ashamed I didn't know it.</sup>