# Is "what they claimed to be the inside story" grammatically right?

Tags: grammar, sentence-usage, parenthesis

In Page 52 of **COLLINS COBUILD ENGLISH GUIDES (REPORTING) (Geoff Thompson)**,there are some example sentences:

1. I was looking at the scallops, or what **they claim** are scallops.
2. The Times and the Daily Mail published what **they claimed to be** the inside story.

Also, like sentence 2, from [CBS News](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/splash-mountain-water-ebay-after-disney-world-ride-close-last-day/):

> The Splash Mountain ride at Walt Disney World officially closed for good on Jan. 23 and it will get an upgrade with a new theme. After the ride's final run, sellers on eBay started to list **what they claimed to be** water from the log-flume ride.

I understand "they claim" in the first sentence as a parenthetical structure.But when it comes to the second sentence, I get confused.

After googling,[here](https://gmatclub.com/forum/the-electronics-company-has-unveiled-what-it-claims-to-be-the-world-s-198255.html) is a similar sentence. However,the same structure is not right according the answer.

So, is "what they claimed to be" not the right usage? Or is it obsolete?

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me (I get pop-ups that I can't dismiss), but the usage is perfectly normal and correct. The meaning is that the newspapers published a story which, **so they claimed**, was  'the inside story' (the true, intimate details).

Comment: @KateBunting Which link? 'What they claimed is...' is normal but not for 'what they claimed to be water'.If can not open the link, you could search "The electronics company has unveiled what it claims to be the world’s smallest network digital camcorder, the length of which is that of a handheld computer, and it weighs less than 11 ounces." in google.It is a GMAT test.

Comment: What @KateBunting said - the text as cited is perfectly normal English. But note that *what they claimed **was** water from the log-flume ride* is also perfectly okay. Also note that it's not 'what they claimed to be water' - it's 'what they claimed to be **water from  the log-flume ride**.'

Comment: No, it is not obsolete.  Be aware that newspapers and other news outlets, many of them, deliberately write at a level of complexity suitable for children in elementary school. They simplify wherever possible. That excludes more complicated constructions from "general circulation" and you'll only find them in books and magazines for a more educated audience.  https://centerforplainlanguage.org/what-is-readability/

Comment: The link 'here is a similar sentence', but as you have now quoted the sentence I don't need to look it up. It's perfectly correct; the company claims that their camcorder is the world's smallest.

Comment: The fact that the main verb is ***claim*** is of no special relevance. Compare *I know John **is** honest* and *I know John **to be** honest*. The latter (subjunctive) construction is a bit more "literary, formal", but they're both perfectly natural, and mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi, where can I find this relevant usage that "I know John to be honest." is more "literary, formal" than "I know John is honest"? Are there some terminologies about this？

Comment: @KateBunting But, this is not the right option. The right is "The electronics company has unveiled what it claims is the world’s smallest network digital camcorder, which is as long as a handheld computer and weighs less than 11 ounces." In the aspect of grammar, are they all right? But is the latter appropriate?

Comment: It works exactly the same as the 'Times' sentence - the company has unveiled a camcorder which, **so it claims**, is the worlds smallest... The sentence goes on to say more about the size and weight of the device.

Comment: @WingledTiger: I don't understand. Are you saying you don't believe my assertion that the subjunctive construction *(Think him **to be..**)* is a bit more "literary, formal" than Simple Present *(Think he **is...**)*? If I google "is subjunctive in english formal", what shows as the top "snippet view" for me is: *The subjunctive was formerly used in English for situations that were improbable or that expressed a wish. It is only rarely used in modern British English. It is, however, found in certain set phrases and in very formal forms of speech and writing.* Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @FumbleFingers What I mean is where can I find some books which introduce this kind of usage? Moreover, how do you know this usage "I know John to be honest"?I want to know this kind of usage systematically,.

Comment: @WingledTiger: For example, there's [What does "You know it to be true" mean? Is it grammatically correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/283616/) as asked here on ELL, and ["I know him ʙᴇɪɴɢ honest" vs “I know him ᴛᴏ ʙᴇ honest”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500735/) on ELU. But this is all very complicated / formal / outdated stuff to do with ***subjunctive*** constructions. Which you hardly ever really *need* today, so if you find it difficult, you could just ignore it and use the Simple Present forms *I know it **is** true, I know he **is** honest*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much for your patient explanation! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are interrogative content clauses. You can understand their meaning by thinking of the answer to the corresponding question.

> ...scallops, or what they claim are scallops.

So, the question is "What do they claim are scallops?"  and the answer would be "That fishy food". The interrogative content clause means "that fishy food"

You can use "claim" in two ways:  "They claim (that) these are scallops", and "They claim these to be scallops". So you could form an interrogative content clause in two ways  "what they claim are scallops", and "what they claim to be scallops". There's very little difference between these two ways of using "claim".

Interrogative content clauses can fulfil many of the functions of noun phrases. So the direct object of "published" can be either a noun phrase "He published (the inside story)", or a content clause "He published (what he claimed to be the inside story)"